# Javascript prototypal inheritance and object creation

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, javascript-objects

I cant understand the differences between the normal object and inheritance creation process and the whole `prototype` concept. Let's say I have this code:

```
function Person(name, age,location){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.location = location;
    this.greet = function(){
        return console.log(this.name + " says hi from "+this.location);
    }
}
    Person.prototype = {
        protoGreet: function(){
            console.log(this.name + " says 'that greeting was sent using a prototype'")
        }
    }

var alex = new Person("Alex",29,"earth");
var john = Object.create(Person);
//now I can set john's location john.location = "wherever";
```

1. Whats the difference between `greet` and `protoGreet` methods. They both act completely the same.
2. What is the difference between `alex` and `john`. One was created using the `new` keyword and the other one thru the `prototype` property of `Person` "class".
3. I guess there's no *right* way because both are correct, but when should I prefer one method over the other?

Comment: There is a `greet` function created for every `Person` instance, whereas there's only one `protoGreet` function, which is shared between all instances.

Comment: generally, it's handy to code generic methods on the prototype and properties and protected methods in-constructor. if all objects need it, use proto, if only some do, do it in-constructor.

Comment: `Object.create(Person)` should be `Object.create(Person.prototype)`, and then the difference is that none of the work done in the `Person` constructor will have been applied to the `john` object, unless you do `Person.call(john, "John", 20, "mars")`

Comment: 1. What do I care how many instances of `greet` are there? Performance? 
2. What are the benefits of having only one *shared* instance of a certain method?
3. Under what circumstances I dont need/want/have to to use the original constructor?
4. In case I create an object using the `Object.create(Person.prototype)`, where does the magic happen? In the constructor of `Object`?

Answer (score 2):

Difference between prototype functions and object itself functions:
**greet function**: This function (all functions are objects) is inside of the instance object so each instance has its own greet function, as you can see in the picture.

**protoGreet function**: Located inside an independent object in the memory (the literal object in the picture) and is not owned by any instances of `Person`. But each instance of the `Person` has a hidden link (reference) to that object (this link is called __proto__). So this object is shared among all instances of the `Person`

[image]

> What do I care how many instances of greet are there?

Memory optimization is an essence for all applications and actually there is no exceptions for web applications. So when a single shared object is adequate for your purpose, using separate object for each instance could violate this rule. But as performance point of view the first way (i.e greet function) can be faster than the second one (i.e protoGreet function) because a certain process called prototype chain lookup does not take place. Keep in mind that in this trade-off memory is the winner.

For your other questions, Seems you don't know what exactly is done by `new` keyword. So let me point you out to a side note.

Note: These steps is going to be done when you invoke a function with `new` keyword. Suppose we have the following function:

```
function Person (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

- Create an empty literal object i.e `{}` (Note that the hidden __proto__ link of this object refers to the object represented by `Person.prototype`)
- Invoke the function and substitute all `this` keywords with this emply literal object (In more technical words, `this` refers to that empty literal object).
- The specified properties and methods will be added to that newly created object. (In this case `name` and `age` properties).
- Finally that object implicitly will be returned from the function.

Now lets come back to your question, What's differences between `Object.create(Person.prototype)` and `new Person()` ?

Case `new Person()` was discussed earlier above. But `Object.create(Person.prototype)` creates an empty object and links its __proto__ to the first input argument object (In this case `Person.prototype`) and return that newly created object as output.

Okay, so far I hope that this notes clarify your problems, But if my answer still doesn't make sense let me know where's your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please refer to the following questions as well? 1. What do I care how many instances of greet are there? Performance? 2. What are the benefits of having only one shared instance of a certain method? 3. Under what circumstances I dont need/want/have to to use the original constructor? 4. In case I create an object using the Object.create(Person.prototype), where does the magic happen? In the constructor of Object?

Comment: thanks! still some things not entirely clear. The creation of an object is done via literal expression or the `new` keyword, but the inheritance is done by `Object.create(Person.prototype)` or for example `jon=new Person()`? When would I prefer to use one method over the other?

Comment: @undroid In my opinion object creation using `new` could be adequate in all major purposes. Also note that prototype chaining is also applied via `new` object creation (As I previously mentioned in my last update)