# Accessing Javascript object prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

As I understand, in JavaScript every object has a `prototype` and it exposes some default properties. I have the following code where I'm trying to set the Year property of two objects through `prototype`. But both the calls are failing.

How can I override `toLocalString()` for any object if I don't have access to the `prototype`? Please note that the following code is to test on the `prototype` property, but my intention is to override the `toLocalString()` method.

```
var car = {
    Make: 'Nissan',
    Model: 'Altima'
};

car.Year = 2014;
alert(car.Year);

alert(car.prototype); // returns undefined

car.prototype.Year = 2014; // Javascript error

// --------------

function Car() {
    this.Make = 'NISSAN';
    this.Model = 'Atlanta';
}

var v = new Car();
v.prototype.Year = 2014; // JavaScript error
alert(v.prototype);
```

Comment: In your bottom example, it should be `Car.prototype.Year = 2014` - you set the prototype on the object function - not the created instance.

Comment: Do you mean `toLocaleString()` instead of `toLocalString()` or do you want to implement your own method `toLocalString()`?

Comment: Please have look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26149216/1841194)

Comment: The `prototype` property belongs on a *function*. The function uses that `prototype` property when called with `new` to construct instance objects. Setting `prototype` on a non-function object has no effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do have access to the prototype property, but it is only present on `Function`s.

```
var car = {
    Make: 'Nissan',
    Model: 'Altima'
};
```

This is the same as:

```
var car = new Object();
car.Make = 'Nissan';
car.Model = 'Altima';
```

So, `car.__proto__ === Object.prototype`.

And `car.prototype === undefined` as the `prototype` property is only present on `Function`s (as I already said).

```
function Car() {
    this.Make = 'NISSAN';
    this.Model = 'Atlanta';
}
```

Here `Car.prototype` points to an instance of `Object` because `Car` is a function and when function declarations are evaluated their `prototype` is set to an instance of `Object`.

```
Car.prototype.Year = 2014; //all Car *instances* will have a Year property set to 2014 on their prototype chain.

var c = new Car(); //create an instance
console.log(c.Year); //2014
```

Overriding a method present on the prototype chain for an object is as simple as creating a corresponding method on the object:

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.toLocaleString = function() {
  //my own implementation
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to modify the constructor function prototype:

```
function Car(year, make, model) {
  this.year  = year;
  this.make  = make;
  this.model = model;
}

Car.prototype.toLocaleString = function() {
  return [this.year, this.make, this.model].join(' ');
};

var civic = new Car(2014, 'Honda', 'Civic');
civic.toLocaleString(); // => "2014 Honda Civic"
```

This [MDN article on `Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) might be helpful.